# UDL2 Folding style 2 only work with Windows EOL but not UNIX EOL

Tags: notepad++

With the following setting in UDL2.1.0.12

```
Folding in code 2 style:
open: function
close: "end function"

operators1: ( )
```

on the following code

```
function test1(x)
end function test1

function test2(y)
end function test2
```

will work with windows EOL but not with UNIX EOL

Is the setting above correct?

Comment: if you are waiting for another answer (possibly better), keep answers unmarked. Otherwise please mark the answer (of course, only if it answered the question) so this Q&A gets closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of UDL. I can confirm that this is a known bug, and it will be solved in UDL3.0 phase. In the mean time, you can use this beta version http://goo.gl/Bo3emS 
Note however, that this beta is few months old, and it will downgrade your Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

I have played with it and it looks like an obvious defect.

See the visualization – compare first and second half of the example:
 [image]

A look at bugtracker reveals **this is known defect** - [#4740](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/4740/).
Subscribe to given bugtracker entry to get notified with any new post inside the bug report (including fix availability).